# Adding incomplete columns to a table

Tags: r, na

I'm new to R and picking it up pretty quick, I think, but I've hit a wall and I'm not even sure what to google to figure this out for myself.

In the code excerpt below, i'm adding a few calculated columns to table ALLDATA. The problem is with the last line. If I have an ALLDATA table where every entry has an associated QCAnalysisNumber, the code works fine. If only SOME of the entries have a QCAnalysis number, that column doesn't populate at all. I would like it to find an appropriate QCAnalysisNumber, and if it can't, just be NA or let me insert text like "No QCAnalysisNumber".

Can you guys tell me where I'm going wrong or point me in the right direction? Even just appropriate search terms for google would be a huge help. Thanks!

```
ALLDATA$IntResult <- round(ALLDATA$Value, 0)

ALLDATA$ComboResult <- ifelse(toupper(ALLDATA$DetectedResult)=="N", ALLDATA$Value/2, round(ALLDATA$Value, 0))

ALLDATA$ND15Result <- ifelse(toupper(ALLDATA$DetectedResult)=="N", ALLDATA$Value/2, ALLDATA$Value) 

ALLDATA$LogComboResult <- ifelse(ALLDATA$DetectedResult=="N", log10(abs(ALLDATA$Value/2)), log10(abs(ALLDATA$Value)))

ALLDATA$LogResult <- log10(abs(ALLDATA$Value))

ALLDATA$QCAnalysisNumber <- ALLDATA$AnalysisNumber[ALLDATA$QCSampleCode!="O" & 
 ALLDATA$LongName==ALLDATAQC$LongName & 
 ALLDATA$SampleDate_D==ALLDATAQC$SampleDate_D]
```

Comment: your code is not reproducible without sharing the contents of `ALLDATA`

Comment: That will be difficult, my code takes ALLDATA straight from a local database.

I'll try to reduce this down to a simpler piece of code.

Comment: Will [match](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) help? Also consider using [within](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/with.html).

Comment: Thanks I'll check the documentation for those and check them out.

After a little more testing, I still seem to have the same problem - if there's even one case where the match/within/boolean criteria are unable to find a result, the "QCAnalysisNumber" column is not created at all. Instead, I'd prefer to create the column with NA's when no result is found.

Comment: After some more work, I've made progress on the problem and I'm almost there.

Some simplified code is shown below. Now it makes the QCAnalysisNumber column, but mistakenly reports "2 NA 2 NA" in the final column, when it should report "2 NA NA NA".

I'm trying to tell it to match the number where LongName and SampleDate_D match each entry, and NA where there is no complete match.

Comment: forgot the code:

`TestData <- array(c(1,2,3,4,"aluminum","aluminum","iron","aluminum","O","DUP","O","O","2015/03/01","2015/03/01","2015/03/01","2015/03/02"),c(4,4))

colnames(TestData) <- c("Number","LongName","QCSampleCode","SampleDate_D")

TestData <- as.data.frame(TestData)

TestData$SampleDate_D <-as.Date(TestData$SampleDate_D)

TestDataQC<- subset(TestData,TestData$QCSampleCode!="O")

TestData$QCAnalysisNumber = TestDataQC$Number[TestDataQC$LongName==TestData$LongName & TestDataQC$SampleDate_D==TestData$SampleDate_D]

TestData

TestDataQC`

Comment: Code in comments is generally unreadable. I suggest to heavily edit your question to avoid getting closed. Direct answer to the title: It can't be done - lengths should match. Another option is to assign NAs everywhere and then fix those elements you find valid.